# set specific port on all incoming mssql requests

Tags: sql-server, firewall, port

I connect from my LAMP server to another MSSQL server (through php) at 1433.
But all incoming activity from that connection is coming to random ports on my server
and because of that I cannot start my firewall. (asf)
How can I restrict it to one incoming port , in order to declare it on my firewall ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `is coming to random ports on my server` - no it's not. Here MSSQL is the server - your LAMP machine (which is acting as the client in this conversation) will only ever connect to a single port on the server. Each socket has 2 end points - the client end will have a random value.

Comment: Any ideas on how to set up my firewall (apf) ?

Comment: No - because we don't know how it's set up already. Also you don't say *which* firewall you want to set up (apf is a tool for configuring iptables - i.e. it runs on the Linux end - but since the DBMS is acting as server in this instance, one would usually begin by configuring it's firewall).

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is how most TCP connections work, a random high port is selected as the source port for connections, while a specific port (1433 in this case) is the destination. This is normal.

If you intend to block outgoing traffic from your web server, perhaps you could create a rule allowing outgoing traffic from your web server to your DB server? Also if your firewall does [stateful packet inspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall) then it should understand to allow traffic in on the source port as it will be for an existing connection.